# Spark Streaming - Identify Incoming File Format

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, avro, parquet

I am working on a framework that can take input as a set of files normalize the incoming set of files into a common format and output them into hdfs.
The framework will take in files of different formats csv, parquet & avro each one of them having different compression schemes.

I tried to fetch and normalize the files using below code. CSV files are read properly from the stream but AVRO data files are not read correctly, getting garbage values while reading it.

```
// Receive streaming data from the source
JavaReceiverInputDStream < File > files = streamingContext.socketStream(
 HOST,
 PORT, in -> {
  File file = File.createTempFile("Normalized ", String.valueOf(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()));
  FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
  List < File > out = new ArrayList < > ();
  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( in , StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
   for (String line;
    (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    //     System.out.println(line+" rrr____");
    fileWriter.append(normalize(line)); // Normalizes each String and appends to a CSV file.
   }
   fileWriter.flush();
   fileWriter.close();
  }
  out.add(file);
  return out;
 },
 StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());
```

[image: Code Output, Can read CSV Files properly but getting garbage values while reading AVRO data]

Data from AVRO file is getting corrupted while data from CSV file is printing correctly.

I wrote a class to test working of my above code to normalize the files, files are sent continuously on the socket for testing.

```
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT); 
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());) {
         byte[] buf = null;
         int n = 0;
         while (true) {
          buf = new byte[4092];
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(eventQueue.take()); //takes the file from queue and send it over network on a socket.
          while ((n = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
           dos.write(buf, 0, n);
           dos.flush();
          }
         }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Server error", e);
        }
```

**My Questions -**

1. Is my approach to read the stream of data coming from a Socket correct ?
2. How can i identify the incoming file format while receiving data in Spark Streaming and provide different implementation of reading the files of different format. (To achieve best way to read each format of file efficiently).
3. Should i use Kafka to fetch data from socket and pass to Spark Streaming, Will Kafka would be good to use in this scenario ?

Any help and feedback will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: It's almost (probably literally is) impossible to identify a stream format or data encoding just from the data itself.  That's why most people use a transport with an embedded type field, like mime-type.  Basically what's wrong is it can't be done, your whole concept is hopeless.  Figure out how to get the other end to send you the type, it's the only way.